# Django template failling despite my effort to learn it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

categories.html # this is what i want to be called by `CategoryView.as_view()` which never works. Howevwer index.html works but i have hardcoded the link as follows within index.html. Although index.html extends base.html which is where am outputing the url.
Edit: Avoid confusion this is what is available in index.html template which i guess should work but shows the following error for index now `Page not found (404)`

```
<li><a href="{% url 'all_categories' %}">All</a></li>
```

from my root directory when i type http://127.0.0.1:8000 it works but i want something like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cartegories/`(`index.html` or `categories.html`) i assume the index.html or categories.html is not visible when typed, which is fine.

I can’t believe this is taking me 12hours with all possible intuitive tweaking still can’t get it to work. Please someone advise what am doing wrong. In essense i am just outputing hellow world in categories.html but later i would iterate through and list all the categories in my blog… if `hello world` can’t work then nothing will..

```
#posts urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import IndexView, CategoryView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^all_categories$', CategoryView.as_view(), name='all_categories'),

    # stuff i have tried

]

#admin urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/', include('posts.urls', namespace="posts")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Comment, Category, Reply
from django.views import generic

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

class CategoryView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/categories.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'
    model = Category


#modesl.py

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('all_categories')

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    …
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def save(self, *args, **kargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the URLs in the files solved the problem. Generally, the order of the main `urls.py` is important for readability but the `/` slash did the trick

```
#admin urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/', include('posts.urls', namespace="posts")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
]
```

Also in the post/url.py file i added a `/` at the end of the regex

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^categories/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name='all_categories'),

]
```

Finally in the template the `html` read as follows:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'posts:all_categories' %}">All</a></li>
```